# Docker Swarm service - Change the service mode from replicas to global without recreating the docker service

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

How can we change the service mode from replicas to global mode with recreating the   docker service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. That is not a supported feature of `docker service update`. You'll need to delete the service and recreate.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change back to global mode. This is because Docker Service Update does not support dash dash mode.

You actually have to remove and reissue the Service Creation Command, changing it to dash dash mode global.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a hacky way to do it if you absolutely can't recreate the service.

**Disclaimer**:

`Worked on my machine`

```
replicas=`docker node ls | grep '' --count`

docker service scale [SERVICE NAME]=$replicas
```

Comment: This does not change the service to global nor will it ensure that the service will run on every node e.g. if you were to add a new node to the swarm at a later date you would need to run this command again